# Sqoop2: Build fails: Missing org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter

Tags: maven, sqoop2

When building Sqoop2 with:

mvn package -Pbinary

I get an error:

"A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter"

How to build Sqoop2?

I am runing:

Apache Maven 3.2.1

Java version: 1.7.0_51

CentOS 6.5, kernel 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site (packaging-documentation) on project sqoop-docs: Execution packaging-documentation of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0-beta-3/maven-site-plugin-3.0-beta-3.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1.3/doxia-sink-api-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1.3/doxia-logging-api-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.3/doxia-core-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.3/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.1.3/doxia-module-apt-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.1.3/doxia-module-xdoc-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.3/doxia-module-fml-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.3/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.3/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-doxia-tools/1.2.1/maven-doxia-tools-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/1.0-beta-6/wagon-file-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/nekohtml/xercesMinimal/1.9.6.2/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.6.2/nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-6/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.38/jsch-0.1.38.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-common/1.0-beta-6/wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-external/1.0-beta-6/wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ftp/1.0-beta-6/wagon-ftp-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/2.0/commons-net-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit/1.0-beta-6/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-webdav/1.5.0/jackrabbit-webdav-1.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons/1.5.0/jackrabbit-jcr-commons-1.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-scm/1.0-beta-6/wagon-scm-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-manager-plexus/1.0/maven-scm-manager-plexus-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.4/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.10/plexus-utils-1.5.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.25/jetty-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.25/jetty-util-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.3/slf4j-api-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.3/slf4j-simple-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.1/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/home/dk/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonatype.aether.graph.DependencyFilter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sqoop-docs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Maven version I need to build Sqoop2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036248/which-maven-version-i-need-to-build-sqoop2)

Answer (score 24):

Change your maven-site-plugin to version 3.3

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
```

Change this to

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
```

Answer (score 10):

You should update the maven-site-plugin to the version 3.3  or later...

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound