# Which Maven version I need to build Sqoop2

Tags: maven, sqoop2

Please help to build Sqoop2 from source. I use Maven 3.2.1 on CentOS 6.5.
When I try to compile Sqoop2 with command:

```
mvn compile
```

I get exception resulting from:

```
missing org.apache.sqoop:sqoop-core:test-jar:tests:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

When I try to build Sqoop2 with command:

```
mvn package -Pbinary
```

I get exception resulting from:

```
Missing org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.graph.DependencyFilter

was reported in Hadoop as [HADOOP-10092](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10092) and fixed by bumping `maven-site-plugin` from 3.0 to 3.3.

It looks like sqoop's `sqoop2` branch is [using the same outdated version in `docs/pom.xml`](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/0eb2352411a60073591ed0f51d0f5673c216d6b9/docs/pom.xml#L58):

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0-beta-3</version>
```

I'd suggest trying the same fix.

Comment: Thanks! Changing version to 3.3 solved this error and brought the next one: '[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files .... [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ... java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)'...

Comment: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101128/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space).

Answer (score 0):

you should run `mvn install` before attempting to package it (or just run them together: `mvn install package -Pbinary`).

Any maven 3.x version should be supported, but Just to be on the safe, here's the configuration I validated works properly:

```
mureinik@mycomputer sqoop (sqoop2)]$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: I use latest Maven 3.2.1. I tried 'mvn install' and still get the same: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site (packaging-documentation) on project sqoop-docs: Execution packaging-documentation of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3:site:` **org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter**